# Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Permission denied on resource project mots-dc640., cause=null}

Tags: flutter, firebase

App picking old firebase account that is deleted.I deleted a firebase project and created another one, but the app is still looking for the old account to connect to

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this by executing in my project console:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```